# Drools. cannot be cast to java.lang.Number

Tags: events, casting, drools, drools-fusion

I have these declarations:

```
 declare Event
     @role(event)
     @timestamp(time)
     //@expires(100ms)
     //params : Map<String, Object> 
     param : long
     time : long    
 end


 declare Expectation
     event: Event
     state: int //-1 pending, 0 violated, 1 fulfilled
 end

 declare ExpectationLeftArmStr extends Expectation
 end
```

And in a rule I've written:

```
  ExpectationLeftArmStr exp = new ExpectationLeftArmStr();
  exp.setEvent($ev);
  exp.setState(-1);//pending
  insert(exp);
```

And `$ev` is a correct Event that I use into a rule.
The error is: `rec.dom.LeftArmStr cannot be cast to java.lang.Number` where `LeftArmStr` is `$ev`.

```
Exception in thread "main" Exception executing consequence for rule "Operazions on LeftArmStr event    33399" in rec.dom: java.lang.ClassCastException: rec.dom.LeftArmStr cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at org.drools.runtime.rule.impl.DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.java:39)
    at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireActivation(DefaultAgenda.java:1297)
    at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireNextItem(DefaultAgenda.java:1221)
    at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1456)
    at org.drools.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:710)
    at org.drools.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:674)
    at org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:230)
    at org.rec.Session.notify(Session.java:136)
    at org.ece.reasoner.ReasonerECE.notifyEvent(ReasonerECE.java:73)
    at org.ece.main.MainLaucher.main(MainLaucher.java:245)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: rec.dom.LeftArmStr cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at org.drools.base.evaluators.BeforeEvaluatorDefinition$BeforeEvaluator.evaluateCachedRight(BeforeEvaluatorDefinition.java:306)
    at org.drools.rule.constraint.EvaluatorConstraint.isAllowedCachedRight(EvaluatorConstraint.java:80)
    at org.drools.common.SingleBetaConstraints.isAllowedCachedRight(SingleBetaConstraints.java:134)
    at org.drools.reteoo.JoinNode.propagateFromRight(JoinNode.java:156)
    at org.drools.reteoo.JoinNode.assertObject(JoinNode.java:148)
    at org.drools.reteoo.SingleObjectSinkAdapter.propagateAssertObject(SingleObjectSinkAdapter.java:59)
    at org.drools.reteoo.AlphaNode.assertObject(AlphaNode.java:141)
    at org.drools.reteoo.SingleObjectSinkAdapter.propagateAssertObject(SingleObjectSinkAdapter.java:59)
    at org.drools.reteoo.ObjectTypeNode.assertObject(ObjectTypeNode.java:235)
    at org.drools.reteoo.EntryPointNode.assertObject(EntryPointNode.java:240)
    at org.drools.common.NamedEntryPoint.insert(NamedEntryPoint.java:350)
    at org.drools.common.NamedEntryPoint.insert(NamedEntryPoint.java:311)
    at org.drools.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.insert(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:903)
    at org.drools.base.DefaultKnowledgeHelper.insert(DefaultKnowledgeHelper.java:192)
    at org.drools.base.DefaultKnowledgeHelper.insert(DefaultKnowledgeHelper.java:186)
    at rec.dom.Rule_Operazions_on_LeftArmStr_event____33399_4678ddba7e884b11b1acf302cef8a05c.defaultConsequence(Rule_Operazions_on_LeftArmStr_event____33399_4678ddba7e884b11b1acf302cef8a05c.java:19)
    at rec.dom.Rule_Operazions_on_LeftArmStr_event____33399_4678ddba7e884b11b1acf302cef8a05cDefaultConsequenceInvokerGenerated.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at rec.dom.Rule_Operazions_on_LeftArmStr_event____33399_4678ddba7e884b11b1acf302cef8a05cDefaultConsequenceInvoker.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireActivation(DefaultAgenda.java:1287)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: i read this post http://goo.gl/ogeIZ8
may be a bug that does not allow you to enter events as parameters?

Comment: Quote: And $ev is a correct Event that i use into a rule. the error is "rec.dom.LeftArmStr cannot be cast to java.lang.Number" where LeftArmStr is $ev. End quote - This is ambiguous. Is the type of $ev the declared Event or LeftArmStr?

Comment: $ev is LeftArmStr that extends Event

Comment: This may be a bug but it's impossible to tell from the way you post your code. A complete (!) set of code reproducing the effect and the Drools version you use is required. I recommend the Drools user list.